SQL - Combining a GROUP BY with a COUNT DISTINCT PARTITION BY
Hey I am trying to figure out if this is possible to do in one query or if I need to use a CTE because windows functions are calculated after group bys.
Raw Table:



Day
Week
Item
Store
Channel
Qty




1/1/24
1
a
1a
Online
4


1/1/24
1
a
1a
In Person
3


1/1/24
1
b
1a
In Person
9


1/7/24
2
b
1a
Online
3


1/7/24
2
b
2a
Online
4


1/7/24
2
b
3a
In Person
3



Expected Table:



Week
Item
Channel
SUM_QTY
CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM_CHNL
CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM




1
a
Online
4
1
2


1
a
In Person
3
1
2


1
b
In Person
9
1
1


2
b
Online
7
2
3


2
b
In Person
3
1
3



Metrics:

CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM_CHNL - Count Distinct of Stores when Qty > 0 grouped by Week, Item, and Channel
CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM - Count Distinct of Stores when Qty > 0 grouped by Week and Item.

I am currently doing this via a CTE to calculate the CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM at the Week and item granularity then joining it onto the Week, Item, Channel granularity.
When I do a query leveraging a window function to try and do this in one query - I will get an error. Is this possible to do it in one query?
Error:
SQL compilation error:
[IFF(QTY > (CAST(0 AS FLOAT)), Stpre, SYSTEM$NULL_TO_FIXED(null))] is not a valid group by expression

Query:
SELECT
   WEEK
    , ITEM
    , CHANNEL
    , SUM(QTY) AS SUM_TY_QTY
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN STORE END)::INT AS CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM_CHNL
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN STORE END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY WEEK, ITEM) AS CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM

FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1;


your output sum_qty is incorrect for the example data: the 2, b, in persorn sum is 3.

When you do an OVER you are defining how to window on a per row bais, as compared to the higher-order GROUP BY frame of reference. Thus the CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM needs to be integrated into what you are intending in the framing of your week, item, channel group by context.
This can be seen by removing the two aggregate values, and the group by clause:
with data(day, week, item, store, channel, qty) as (
    select * from values
    ('1/1/24'::date, 1, 'a', '1a', 'Online',    4),
    ('1/1/24'::date, 1, 'a', '1a', 'In Person', 3),
    ('1/1/24'::date, 1, 'b', '1a', 'In Person', 9),
    ('1/7/24'::date, 2, 'b', '1a', 'Online',    3),
    ('1/7/24'::date, 2, 'b', '2a', 'Online',    4),
    ('1/7/24'::date, 2, 'b', '3a', 'In Person', 3)    
)
SELECT
   WEEK
    , ITEM
    , CHANNEL
    --, SUM(QTY) AS SUM_TY_QTY
    --, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN STORE END)::INT AS CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM_CHNL
    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN STORE END) OVER (PARTITION BY WEEK, ITEM) AS CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM
FROM data
--GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1;




WEEK
ITEM
CHANNEL
CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM




1
a
Online
1


1
a
In Person
1


1
b
In Person
1


2
b
Online
3


2
b
Online
3


2
b
In Person
3



How you want this to interact with your GROUP BY needs solving. And thus if your question is does this need to be done is a different scope layer, then the answer is yes.
Be that a sub-select or a CTE (given they amount to the same thing, inside a signle use context)

Thanks, Simeon! I am mainly wondering if this is possible to be done in one select statement. I have my solution working with a CTE, but it was more of a curious question.

I was explianing why your question shows you are not understanding what is happening, and thus why the question should not really be asked, because "there cannot be in one" because "in one" has no true meaning.

Let's try to sum up what has been counted.
SELECT
  week,
  item,
  channel,
  sum(qty) as sum_qty,
  count(*) as CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM_CHNL,
  sum(count(*))
    over(partition by week, item) as CNT_DSNT_STR_WEEK_ITEM
FROM "table"
group by week, item, channel
order by week, item, channel desc;

Result.
+------+------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| week | item |  channel  | sum_qty | cnt_dsnt_str_week_item_chnl | cnt_dsnt_str_week_item |
+------+------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
|    1 | a    | Online    |       4 |                           1 |                      2 |
|    1 | a    | In Person |       3 |                           1 |                      2 |
|    1 | b    | In Person |       9 |                           1 |                      1 |
|    2 | b    | Online    |       7 |                           2 |                      3 |
|    2 | b    | In Person |       3 |                           1 |                      3 |
+------+------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------------+

